# How to limit query by date

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to  limit the query to show only the results from the last 7 days (always from Friday), i.e. from the previous Friday from (12:01) to the current Friday (11:59).
I'm using woocommerce wp_wc_order_product_lookup and want to show exactly that orders from this range

Comment: Not a bad question but needs more info. Try showing us what you have already attempted. Are you asking how to get the dates? are you asking how to write the query within wordpress? are you just asking for a raw query. What query did you come up with in your first attempt at this?

Comment: Thank you for your anserw. I ask about raw query, because i will cause script by crone once a weekd in 12:30 each friday, unless there is a better way than my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get SQL Select.

```
<?php    
$datetime1 = new DateTimeImmutable('last friday 12:00:00');
$datetime2 = $datetime1->modify('+ 1 week');
$sql = 'SELECT * wp_wc_order_product_lookup
        WHERE date_created BETWEEN 
        ' . $datetime1->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") 
        . ' AND 
        ' . $datetime2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ;

echo $sql; // result: SELECT * table_name WHERE datetime_column_name BETWEEN 2020-04-10 12:00:00 AND 2020-04-17 12:00:00
```